# SQL query with AND?

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a little problem writing a request.
With the data example below, i want to recover the archive_id that have a document_type_id = 18 and 20

```
    +------------+------------------+
    | archive_id | document_type_id |
    +------------+------------------+
    |          1 |               20 |
    |          1 |               18 |
    |          3 |               20 |
    |          4 |               11 |
    |          2 |               23 |
    |          5 |               20 |
    |          6 |               23 |
    |          6 |               20 |
    |          6 |               18 |
    +------------+------------------+
```

Expected result :

```
    +------------+
    | archive_id |
    +------------+
    |          1 |
    |          6 |
    +------------+
```

Same question but with document_type_id = 18, 20 and 23
Expected result :

```
    +------------+
    | archive_id |
    +------------+
    |          6 |
    +------------+
```

Thank for your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For a general solution, you could for example use an array containing the `archive_id`s you are searching for:

```
WITH searched(ids) AS (VALUES (ARRAY[18,20,23]))
SELECT tab.archive_id
FROM tab CROSS JOIN searched
WHERE tab.document_type_id = ANY (searched.ids)
GROUP BY tab.archive_id
HAVING count(DISTINCT document_type_id) = cardinality(searched.ids);
```

Answer (score 4):

A simple having count would do the trick.

First case

```
select archive_id
from your_table
where document_type_id in (18,20)
group by archive_id
having count(distinct document_type_id) =2;
```

https://dbfiddle.uk/MnjR_4a_

Second case

```
select archive_id
from your_table
where document_type_id in (18,20,23)
group by archive_id
having count(distinct document_type_id) =3;
```

https://dbfiddle.uk/v9m3nPiq

Comment: Thanks, i already had this solution, but the number of document_type_id may be different.